# Why is my localStorage data not accessible for different URLs under the same domain?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am making a mobile web application in backbone under:
http://example.com/mobile/index/

After the user logs in I'm storing a token in localStorage and redirecting to a search route within backbone:
http://example.com/mobile/index/search

I was under the impression the localStorage information can be shared across the entire domain but the localStorage token is only accessible from the latter URL. Why is this not the case? How can I share localStorage for the entire example.com domain?

A side-point if anyone know - will information for m.example.com, example.com and www.example.com be shared with a similar approach?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: As the [localStorage is unique for each origin](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute) the answer for your last question is **no** as each of the [resources has a different origin](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454#page-7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should not happen.

1. Are you absolutely sure they have the same origin?  They must have the same:

   - **Subdomains:** `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` are different origins
   - **Protocols:** `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` are different origins
2. Alternatively, it's possible that `localStoarge` might be full, so new data is getting silently ignored.
3. If you are doing development locally, make sure you do not intermix `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` (those a different origins that happen to refer to the same physical machine).
4. If you are doing development locally and loading your page as a `file:` resource (i.e., the URL actually starts with `file://`), browsers may treat each `file:` URL as a distinct origin, or at least treat different directories as different origins.

Comment: You're right it shouldn't happen. For some reason the problem disappeared when I restarted my browser - thanks for clarifying on the sub-domains